# Nothing happens when I click to sort a column in GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have coded my program so that when a user clicks on a column, the data is sorted in ascending/descending order.

When I go to click on a column header, however, nothing actually happens.

I dont get an error or anything.

Here is the code that I am using to sort the records in the GridView:

```
     Property GridViewSortDirection() As SortDirection
        Get
            If IsNothing(ViewState.Item("GridViewSortDirection")) Then
                Return SortDirection.Descending
            End If
            Return ViewState.Item("GridViewSortDirection")
        End Get

        Set(ByVal Value As SortDirection)
            ViewState.Item("GridViewSortDirection") = Value
        End Set

    End Property



    Function GetSortDirection() As SortDirection

        Dim GridViewSortDirectionNew As SortDirection

        Select Case GridViewSortDirection

            Case SortDirection.Descending
                GridViewSortDirectionNew = SortDirection.Ascending

            Case SortDirection.Ascending
                GridViewSortDirectionNew = SortDirection.Descending

            Case Else
                GridViewSortDirectionNew = SortDirection.Descending

        End Select
        GridViewSortDirection = GridViewSortDirectionNew

        Return GridViewSortDirectionNew

    End Function



    Protected Sub GridView_Sorting1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles GridView2.Sorting

        'Dim myPageIndex As Integer = GridView2.PageIndex
        Dim mySortdirection As SortDirection = GetSortDirection()
        'Dim sortExpression = e.SortExpression
        'Dim dv As New DataView()


        If (GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending) Then
            GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending
        Else
            GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending
        End If

    End Sub
```

If anyone could advise, that would be great.

Many thanks,

Dan

Comment: Please show us your gridview design that is in aspx side.

Comment: Where's the data for your GridView coming from?

Comment: Hello,My data is coming from a table in Microsoft SQL Server Express.

Comment: My gridview looks like: <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" Height="143px" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="GridView_Sorting1"

Comment: How are you attaching the data to the grid?

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-query the database with the Order By [COlName] ASC or DESC clause. You get a new dataset which you can bind to your gridview.

Alternatively, you could put the initial results in a dataview then sort it accordingly when you click on the gridview column. This way, you don't have to go to the database again